# Semantic-ui checkbox in Meteor

Tags: checkbox, meteor, semantic-ui

Do anyone know how to use Semantic-ui checkbox (toggle) in Meteor?

```
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" name="public">
 <label>Subscribe to weekly newsletter</label>
</div>
```

The checkbox / slider is visible on the html page with a sliding effect but I cant understand how to code against the control. How to set checked / unchecked depending on a value and how to handel events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```js
Session.set('chosen', false);

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  var $elem = this.$('.checkbox');

  // Use 'set unchecked' or 'set checked' instead of 'uncheck'/'check'
  // to avoid triggering the callback.
  // Set initial state here:
  $elem.checkbox('set ' + (Session.get('chosen') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'));

  // Keep state synced with the session.
  $elem.checkbox({
    onChange: function () {
      Session.set('chosen', !Session.get('chosen'));
    }
  });

});
```